# .htaccess language redirect wont allow subdirectory access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm struggling to get .htaccess to serve a different html file dependant on language.

The file works when i change my language but when i try and access a file in the subdirectory "/friends/" the page wont change. it also changes the url.

here's my script...

```
# Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteEngine on

# language is 'it' italian
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (it) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website1/welcome-italian.php [L]

# fallback to english
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website1/welcome-english.php [L]
```

here is my file structure

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to give full filesystem path in rewrite rule. You only need to provide path from document root.

Try this (assuming document root is `htdocs/website1`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# language is 'it' italian
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (it) [NC]
RewriteRule .* welcome-italian.php [L]

# fallback to english
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en) [NC]
RewriteRule .* welcome-english.php [L]
```

Comment: Hey anubhava, just tried this script but it doesnt seem to work. I now have access to my subdirectories but can no longer change page via languages

Comment: Just fixed it!! In my situation the with the link to the file i had t omit the "/" before the filename. Thank you so much!